# Can 10K+ users see deleted questions?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

After a short discussion in comment with 10K+ user,
I noticed a fatal flaw in the question,
wrote "Thank you" and not before long
deleted the question.

Not sure the 10K+ user saw my final
comment.

> Can 10K+ users see deleted questions
>   and the comments in them?

Comment: It seems you do not really ask what you want to know about. Deleted content especially self-deleted questions can be quite hard to find for 10k+ users
(to see the question you need its URL, but it is gone from [all] lists as it is [self] deleted...)
Depending on circumstqnces a 10k+ user might (with some effort) 
be able to see the question again after deletion. 
Regarding notification of comments on then deleted content there is not special-casing of 10k+. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231668
So if you want to know if a 10k+ will have noticed such a comment the answer is "maybe."

Comment: @quid you appear right. I believe the 10K user would have reloaded the page.

Comment: I would love to recover my own Question which I have foolishly deleted some months ago. I'd like to read it or copy for myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they can. -- See https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/moderator-tools.

Comment: Thank you......